For a given sequence $a$, find $b$ such that $a*b = (0\cdots0, 1, 0\cdots0)$
The discrete convolution (or two-sided Cauchy product) of two sequences $a, b$ is given by:
$$
(a*b)_n := \sum_{m=-\infty}^{+\infty} a_m b_{n-m}
$$

All convergence conditions aside; starting from a known $a$,
is there a systematic way to compute $b$ such that $a*b = \mathbb (1_{n=0})_{n\in\mathbb Z} = (0\cdots0, 1, 0\cdots0)$ ? I am specifically looking for a way that does not involve the Fourier transform or series.

My main motivation for this question is to find the Fourier series of $g:=1/\delta$, the multiplicative inverse of the Dirac impulsion:
$$
g(x) =
\begin{cases}
0 &\text{if } x=0\\
+\infty &\text{else} 
\end{cases}
$$
Since the Fourier sequence of $\delta$ is $a=(1, \cdots, 1, \cdots 1)$, then the sequence $b$ aforementioned would be the Fourier coefficients of $g$. Am I wrong somewhere ?


